# C++. Reading from text file. Every second segment is missing

Tags: c++, getline

I have the following data in a text file:

```
...
A,Q1,1
S,a1,a1
S,a2,a2
S,a3,a3
A,Q1,1
S,b1,b1
S,b2,b2
S,b3,b3
A,Q1,1
S,c1,c1
S,c2,c2
S,c3,c3
A,Q1,1
S,d1,d1
S,d2,d2
S,d3,d3
A,Q2,1
S,x1,x1
S,x2,x2
S,x3,x3
...
```

I use the following code to extract the data:

```
std::string MyClass::getData(const std::string& icao)
{
    // Final String
    std::string finalData = "";

    // Path to the Navigraph Navdata
    std::string path = getPath();

    std::string dataFilePathSmall = navdataFilePath + "ats.txt";

    // Create file streams
    std::ifstream ifsSmall(dataFilePathSmall.c_str());

    // Check if neither of the files exists.

    if (!ifsSmall.is_open())
    {
        // If it does not exist, return Not Available
        finalData = "FILE NOT FOUND";
    }

    // If the file 'ats.txt' exists, pull the data relevant to the passed ICAO code
    if (ifsSmall)
    {
        // We need to look a line starting with the airway prefixed by "A," and suffixed by ','
        const std::string search_string = "A," + icao + ',';

        // Read and discard lines from the stream till we get to a line starting with the search_string
        std::string line;

        // While reading the whole documents
        while (getline(ifsSmall, line))
        {
            // If the key has been found...
            if (line.find(search_string) == 0)
            {
                // Add this line to the buffer
                finalData += line + '\n';

                // ...keep reading line by line till the line is prefixed with "S"
                while (getline(ifsSmall, line) && (line.find("S,") == 0))
                {
                    finalData += line + '\n'; // append this line to the result
                }
            }
        }

        // If no lines have been found
        if (finalData == "")
        {
            finalData = "CODE NOT FOUND";
        }
    }

    // Close the streams if they are open
    if (ifsSmall)
    {
        ifsSmall.close();
    }

    return finalData;
}
```

Now, my problem is that for some reason, every second segment of the data is not read. That is, I receive the following:

```
A,Q1,1
S,a1,a1
S,a2,a2
S,a3,a3
A,Q1,1
S,c1,c1
S,c2,c2
S,c3,c3
```

I cannot figure out what exactly in my code is missing. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why was it down voted? The time would be spent more efficiently, if you could provide help instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (getline(ifsSmall, line) && (line.find("S,") == 0))
```

will read a line and check if it starts with "S". If it doesn't start with "S", the line has still been read. Same is true for your while+if reading lines starting with "A".

Comment: Thank you. That now makes perfect sense. Trying to figure out how to solve this...

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop reads a line not starting with "S" and then terminates. This is the line starting with "A" you are missing. The outer loop then reads another line, so it misses the section start.

Try to use only one loop and one getline().

Comment: Thank you. Not sure though how it is possible to use only one loop and getline in this particular case.

Comment: Actually I do not see why you need the inner loop at all. It seems to do exactly the same as the outer loop (append the current line to a string).

Comment: Because it is supposed to continue reading the file until the necessary prefix is there. Otherwise, I do not see how all the lines starting with "S" that follow the first found line will be added. It worked just fine when there was an empty line between the segments but this is how the database looks now and I can't help it.